# Contingency table for ordered data

Tags: r, contingency

I have a data set with two categorical variables, one of which needs to be ordered (extent)

```
Extent          LOP
Partially       Other
Partially       Other
Not at all      Other
Not at all      Other
Substantially   Other
Substantially   Other
Substantially   LOPA
Fully           LOPA
Fully           Other
```

that I'd like converted into a contingency table of extent frequencies like this:

```
       Extent
  LOP  Not at all Partially Substantially Fully   
  LOPA      0          0         2          1
  Other     2          2         2          1
```

If I use a `with` statement:

```
with(data, table(LOP, Extent))
```

I don't get the ordering of my extent levels as it defaults to alphabetizing the extent.

```
      Extent
  LOP Fully Not at all Partially Substantially    
  LOPA   1       0          0         2          
  Other  1       2          2         2
```

I know I could manually create this table but my data set is much too large for this to be feasible. Any idea of a more efficient way this can be done while keeping my orders?

Comment: @RonakShah I needs to be ordered for a future analysis

Comment: @Lannie84 Are you *sure* your variable `Extent` is ordered? Because I cannot confirm your results as I demonstrate below.

Comment: Are your data `factor`s or `character`s? If the former, then you can redefine the order with `levels(x$Extent) <- c("Not at all","Partially","Substantially","Fully")` and then re-attempt your call to `with(data,table(LOP,Extent))`.

Comment: @r2evans ughhh thank-you I've spent an embarrassingly long amount of time trying to do this simple task!!!

Answer (score 1):

**I am not sure how you got the results you're showing in your main post; both base R's `table` and `tidyr::spread` conserve the order of an `ordered` variable.**

Here is a `tidyverse` option that conserves the order of your `ordered` variable.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    count(Extent, LOP) %>%
    spread(Extent, n, fill = 0)
## A tibble: 2 x 5
#  LOP   `Not at all` Partially Substantially Fully
#  <fct>        <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>
#1 LOPA            0.        0.            1.    1.
#2 Other           2.        2.            2.    1.
```

Actually `table` also conserves the order

```
with(df, table(LOP, Extent))
#       Extent
#LOP     Not at all Partially Substantially Fully
#  LOPA           0         0             1     1
#  Other          2         2             2     1
```

so I am unsure how you got the results in your main post.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Extent          LOP
'Partially'       Other
'Partially'       Other
'Not at all'      Other
'Not at all'      Other
'Substantially'   Other
'Substantially'   Other
'Substantially'   LOPA
'Fully'           LOPA
'Fully'           Other", header = T)

df$Extent <- ordered(df$Extent, levels = c("Not at all", "Partially", "Substantially", "Fully"))
```

Comment: @RonakShah Yes I understand that; but OP states about the variables that *"one of which is ordered (extent)"*. This implies that one variable is already ordered (which is why I included the `ordered` call in the sample data part). If the variable is ordered, both `table` and `tidyr::spread` conserve that order.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. You are right, if it is ordered then `table` should work as well. Not sure how OP is getting the result.

Comment: @RonakShah Seems I misunderstood as well;-) It was a matter of setting `factor`/`ordered` levels.